# how do i call an accsessor method from a different class for an object of that class?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to produce a proceduraly generated 2D map, but i am stuck on creating the accsessor method to just return what type a specific location is.
I created a custom square class that has the variable type and special..

here is the square class

```
public class Square{//custom object for map class
private int type = 0;
private boolean special = false;

public int getType(){//returns type of square
  return type;
}

public boolean isSpecial(){//returns boolean for whether square is special or not
 return special;
}

public void setType(int a){//sets type for square if input is between 1 and 5
if(a>=1&&a<=5){
    type = a;
   }
}

public void setSpecial(){//sets special status to true
special = true;
}
}
```

I've tested the square class to make sure it works, I am getting trouble in my Map class when i try to create a method that returns the type of square at a given coordinates

here is the applicable code from that class

```
public class Map{
private int mapWidth;
private int mapHeight;
Square newMap[][] = new Square[0][0];

public Map(int width, int height){//constructor sets map height and width and instantiates a 2d array with the arguments
  if(width <= 0){//if user inputs numbers less than 1 will set according attribute to 1
    width = 1;
  }
  if (height <= 0){
    height = 1;
  }
  mapWidth = width;
    mapHeight = height;
  Square newMap[][] = new Square[mapWidth][mapHeight];
}

public void create(){



}

public int getWidth(){//accssesor methods
  return mapWidth;
}

public int getHeight(){
  return mapHeight;
}

public int getType(int x, int y){
  return newMap[y][x].getType();
}

}
```

I know that i am probably doing something horribly wrong but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `Square newMap[][] = new Square[mapWidth][mapHeight];`  to `newMap = new Square[mapWidth][mapHeight];` in your constructor of Map class

Comment: You also need to create some `Square` objects. `new Square[mapWidth][mapHeight]` creates a 2D array filled with nulls.